# how to test partial with instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

so i need to test a partial. the partial is rendered by specific action, its something like messages box in facebook. my test looks like this:

```
describe 'partials/_partial.js.erb' do
  it 'displays stuff' do
    render
  end
end
```

i run it, and i know it does what i want because i immediately get

```
Failure/Error: if @items.count > 0

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
```

i do not need to hear that it is a bad practice to use instance vars in a partial, it is already there and i need to work with it. so how do i set @items here...?

UPDATE:

controller action looks like this:

```
def controller_method
    @items = items_method
    render_version(:partial => "partials/_partial.js.erb")
end
```

Comment: can you post the controller action?

Comment: @Gaston its there

Comment: are you sure the test calls the controller? I think it just renders the template.

Comment: i never said i want it to call the controller, i want to know how to fake @items here:)

Comment: does it work using mocha? @item.stubs(:count).returns(0)

Comment: it does but i need actual @items array to be defined. i think i will handle it by literally defining it in 'it' block, just discovered this possibility:p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using rspec. In that case, any instance variables you define during your test will be available for your views (regardless if it's a partial or not).

```
describe "users/_messages" do
  before(:each) do
    # This is available in your view.
    @items = []
  end

  it "renders without error when @items is empty" do
    # Will pass, @items is available
    expect { render }.to_not raise_error
  end

  it "shows a count of how many messages there are" do
    # You can modify it before rendering
    @items << Message.new
    render

    expect(rendered).to have_content "You have 1 message"
  end
end
```